# Controlling HTML5 video with scrollMagic, why stuttured animation / droped frames?

Tags: html, video, frame, scrollmagic

```
Hey SO members,
```

I want to play back and forth a HTML5 video along with the scroll. The animation controls the video frame by frame regarding scroll amount.

I coded (it's lightweight and very simple) this using scrollMagic. The embedded video are lightweight as well (tried ugly/over downscaled videos with same results).

The issue i'm facing is that when you gently scroll, the animation looks barely smooth.
But when scrolling "fast", it's like many frames are dropped.
I would guess it could be normal, should the progress percentage drop from 50% to 75% for example. But it's not. The percentage displayed in the console shows that percentage value updates smoothly, some frames are not painted and result as a chopped animation. I'd like it to be smooth, no matter how fast the user scrolls. Any thoughts ?

https://jsfiddle.net/yumigo/h7g081n6/72/

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out that the video is the key.
The MP4 needs to have a keyframe interval very low (2 in my case, instead of usually 10)  to ensure smooth scrolling, especially when scrolling up.
Also, load the mp4 first as webm playback seems more CPU intensive.
Perfectly smooth now.

I updated my jsfiddle.